# Highlight rows using ngFor in Angular Ionic based on condition

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, ionic3

In my application I am in need to highlight all row's based on count value using ngfor in angular.

I tried and I am able to highlight only the particular row based on my count.Please help

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ypxtr7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

If my count value is 3, I need to highlight the row's with index 0, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change 
     `[ngClass]="(count-1==i)?'newMsg':'oldMsg'"` to 
      `[ngClass]="(count-1>=i)?'newMsg':'oldMsg'"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass a function like

```
[ngClass]="isNew(i)?'newMsg':'oldMsg'"
```

And in the component

```
isNew(index) {
      if (index < this.count) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```